# Bootstrap multiple input form in a table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a table with several informational columns and one input. 
I'm using bootstrap 3.0. 
This is the example:
[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dr2fantr/)

The expected result is:

**6 Columns:**

**1st** and **2nd** : would be string output.

**3rd** would be three inputs: `Number`, `Letter`, `Letter`

The rest are informational columns from three buttons: A, B, C.

The problem is that size of the third column is not matching the rest of the columns: 4, 5, 6.

Is it possible to achieve that only by changing the html?

The code:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email number</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter number" type="number">
    </div>
```

Current wrong state with 3 rows of input:

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? I do not entirely get what you need to do

Comment: The problem is the length of the columns - the input column is longer than expected and showing the values on 3 rows in the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `display:table-cell;` for forms, and adjust width of inputs as you need, something like this:

```css
.form-inline .form-control {
  width: 50px;
  display:table-cell;
}

.form-group{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John </td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email number</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter number" type="number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Enter Letter</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter Letter" type="number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Code Key</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Key" type="text">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-row">
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-default active">
                        <input name="options" id="option1" type="radio"> A
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input name="options" id="option2" type="radio"> B
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input name="options" id="option3" type="radio"> C
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-row">
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-default active">
                        <input name="options" id="option1" type="radio"> A
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input name="options" id="option2" type="radio"> B
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input name="options" id="option3" type="radio"> C
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-row">
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-default active">
                        <input name="options" id="option1" type="radio"> A
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input name="options" id="option2" type="radio"> B
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input name="options" id="option3" type="radio"> C
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've tried the changes that you proposed and I have the expected resutls.Thank you!